# Armazenar no banco de dados ou em sessões

Tags: php

Ao fazer uma pesquisa, deparei-me que alguns colegas armazenam os produtos do carrinho em sessões dessa forma:

```
$_SESSION[cesta][$indice][produto]
```

Particularmente, costumo armazenar os produtos do cliente em uma tabela do banco de dados e depois de um certo período em aberto (tenho um campo StatusCompra = 'A' e a data "NOW()"), por exemplo, 3 dias dependendo do estoque do cliente, o sistema exclui automaticamente.

Porém agora fiquei na dúvida. Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com carrinho de compras em uma loja virtual? me refiro a boas práticas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há um problema com usar só sessão, é que esta por *default* dura muito pouco tempo ([de maneira geral o tempo de vida de uma sessão são 24mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904105/php-sessions-default-timeout)), posso colocar agora no carrinho, vou falar/perguntar à minha namorada/mãe/pai... e daqui a uma/duas horas já lá não estar, neste cenário é "mau" porque há muito pouca margem de manobra (tempo) para o utilizador conservar os produtos "candidatos" a serem comprados. Neste caso o ideal seria reforçar com cookies (a tua maneira também está correta, na base de dados e passados 3 dias estes são eliminados), ou se puderes, alterar o tempo de vida da sessão tal como o colega @TTKDroid menciona na sua resposta (apesar de isto consumir recursos no servidor).

Dito isto, então:

Na realidade depende das tuas necessidades, não existe uma regra para isso, se quiseres guardar de forma permanente o que os utilizadores pensaram, mas não chegaram a comprar, deves inserir na base de dados, se quiseres que seja apenas temporário podes apenas deixar em sessão/cookies.

Acredito que muitos sistemas, principalmente [os grandes](https://www.amazon.com.br/) guardem estes dados de forma permanente, para funcionalidades futuras (ex: algoritmos para saber os interesses e mostrar resultados de acordo com as categorias dos produtos que já estiveram no teu carrinho e/ou que já compraste) ou simplesmente para estatística, como o colega @Daniel Omine disse também pode ajudar em decisões estratégicas de venda.

Tudo depende se achas que vale a pena, tens suporte para, e com que objetivos vais guardar de forma permanente.

Pessoalmente até hoje foi muito raro criar um sistema em que guardasse as informações do carrinho na base de dados, simplesmente porque para a grande parte das lojas online esta informação seria desperdiçada, ou seja, seriam dados que não teriam qualquer objetivo no futuro e só iriam ocupar espaço no disco, e por isso não vale a pena guardar.

Pensando/pesando isto, essa decisão acaba sempre por estar nas mãos dos programadores/responsáveis/donos do sistema.

Comment: A primeira parte da resposta é muito imprecisa. A segunda é especulativa. Não dá pra tomar nenhuma decisão a partir dela.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway a primeira parte não é para decidir nada, é apenas para falar sobre a sessão só por si e apontar uma desvantagem, a duvida do colega passa por aí

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway não é para tomar nenhuma decisão, nenhuma está mal, depende das necessidades. Cabe ao responsável pesar isto e decidir se vale a pena guardar ou não de forma permanente. Não há o certo ou errado, esta decisão é feita consoante o sistema que vai ser trabalhado

Comment: a resposta do @Miguel está correta. O que está "errado",  para o escopo do site SO-pt, é a pergunta pois é baseada em opiniões. Decisões que dependem do modelo de negócios são baseadas em opinião e isso é motivo para fechar uma pergunta. E é exatamente o que descreve a resposta. De um modo geral, o jeito "correto" é salvar o carrinho em banco de dados mesmo que o cart seja abandonado. Esses dados são de extrema importância para entender o comportamento os clientes em diversos aspectos e influenciam diretamente em decisões estratégicas de venda. É um tema amplo e muito profundo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu sei que você espera uma resposta definitiva mas não tem resposta definitiva para essa questão, tudo vai depender da arquitetura da sua aplicação.

Se você for hospedar o sistema em uma webfarm, usar sessão em memória como é habitual não é uma opção, já que cada requisição do cliente pode ser respondida por um servidor diferente. Nesse caso você teria que armazenar em um banco de dados ou ter um servidor de sessões.

Se for usar uma API REST, é recomendável armazenar em banco de dados também.

Você também pode armazenar no cliente, no SessionStorage, caso os dados não sejam críticos. Isso evita o problema de timeout das sessões e não usa espaço de armazenamento no servidor.

Sessions ocupam memória no servidor, em um sistema de larga escala é melhor evitar usar session.

Baseado nesses fatos sugiro o armazenamento em banco de dados ou LocalStorage para uma melhor escalabilidade do seu sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode mudar os parâmetros de timeout de sessão no php

```
// manter sessão por 1 hora
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// cada cliente vai se "lembrar" da sessão por 1hora
session_set_cookie_params(3600);

session_start();
```

Ai vc ajusta por quanto tempo em segundos vc quer que a sua sessão dure.

Tanto extendendo a sessão ou armazenando no banco de dados tem seus prós e contras. Onde no banco de dados vc fica com um monte de lixo que deve ser limpo caso o usuário não proceda com o checkout, a sessão mais longa consome recursos do webserver pelo tempo que vc determinou.